# searchkick filter results by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

so i have this searchkick running fine and perfect.

However i'm wanting to add filters, Just something to filter down the data. I've seen that searchkick has something to do with aggerations.

Heres what i have

```
<div class="panel-body" style="color: #1292fd; font-weight:bold">
      <label for="datefrom">Date From:</label>
      <input type="date" id="datefrom" class="form-control" name="date" value="dd/mm/yyyy">
      <label for="dateto">Date To:</label>
      <input type="date" id="dateto" class="form-control" name="date" value="dd/mm/yyyy">
      <div style="float:right">
        <button class="btn btn-info" name="button">Apply Filters</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm wanting as you can see all this to work in the way that the date from / to is compared against the column `date` in the `Event` table.

Thanks
Sam